# How to set the height and width of default action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How to set the height and width of default action bar? Here I am Using the action bar in overlay mode.That is the action bar as in ICS Gallery application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't change the size of native action bar on ICS.
The height of native action bar is always 48dip(portrait) or 40dip(landscape).

But you can implement your own action bar if you insist on changing its height.